# error while updating to Joomla 3.6.0

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, joomla-3.6

while updating to Joomla 3.6.0 this error occurred:

Duplicate column name 'last_check_timestamp' SQL=ALTER TABLE `#__update_sites` ADD COLUMN `last_check_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0' AFTER `enabled`;

i had the same error while updating to Joomla 3.5.1

what is this? and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into your backend and go to Extensions->Manage->Database

Click the Fix button top left